# How can I disable user accounts for a firebase project from code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can successfully disable user accounts for a project from console (firebase web page) but how can a user from an applicative disable your own user account by code when he wants to do. Also, I don't find help in the new documentation of firebase.

Answer (score 17):

This is a bit old to answer the question. But just for someone who looks for the same answer would get an idea from my answer.

**Using the Admin SDK**

Firebase admin (node.js)- which is not available for Mobile platform - has the ability to do the disabling/deleting the user by using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user). To disable a user, set the **disable** attribute to **TRUE**.

> NOTE: Using the Admin SDK is not possible if your application is
>   browser based application.

[image]

**Using the Realtime Database Rules**

The other option is to restrict the user access (read/write) to database by setting Users table in realtime database. You can add a flag field (**active**) in that table for example:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "3sFGw6zlr8VylNuvmCWd9xG1CQ43" : {
      "active" : true,
      "address" : "#123, City",
      "createdBy" : "2016-12-20",
      "mobile" : "xxxxxxx"
    },
    "posts" : {
    }
}
```

In the above example - "3sFGw6zlr8VylNuvmCWd9xG1CQ43" is the uid generated by firebase authentication. This is the key to join this custom **users** table with firebase user profile. The active field can easily set **true** or **false** with normal database write operation.

And this flag field will be used to check if this account has access to database records. See below for an example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null && root.child('users/' + auth.uid).child('active').val()==true",
    ".write": "auth !== null && root.child('users/' + auth.uid).child('active').val()==true",
  }
}
```

This rule will check if user is logged in and has flag field **active** true. Otherwise, user will not be able to read or write to database. On the user login page, you can also check this flag field for logged in user and logout the user if active field is false, so that user will not be able to log in to system.

EDIT: You can use Cloud Functions (Admin SDK) is available in there. Try to spare sometimes to read about Cloud Functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Firebase Cloud Functions is quite a useful tools for Realtime Database.

Answer (score 5):

Response from firebase-support@google.com:

Thanks for reaching out. Sorry it took to so long to get back to you.
Currently, there's no explicit API to disable a user's account. The existing workaround would be to implement a 'disable' flag for users that would allow you to disable/enable an account. Note that this flag would be stored and maintained in your Firebase database. You could use this in conjunction with security rules so that once an account is disabled, only metadata from admins can be written to the user account.

Comment: Is it possible to sign-up a new user and have "disable" on that sign-up initially and then when an email is sent out to confirm the users email after clicking the link the user is "active"

Comment: @FamicTech, You can make use of email verification flag for this purpose  emailVerified is the flag that you need to look for.