# How to disable/deactivate a user account in firebase programmatically?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to disable/deactivate a firebase user account programmatically?

The admin has the opportunity to do it in the Authentication Tab in the firebase console but how to do it in code?

I have not tried anything in code as i did not find any methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 
Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far. It will help to track the issue and get expert's help.

Comment: This question has been asked a bunch of times... Here's some link [Disable User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105505/firebase-how-to-disable-user-using-cloud-function) and [disable user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466314/how-can-i-disable-user-accounts-for-a-firebase-project-from-code) and [disable user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140441/how-to-disable-user-accounts-on-firebase-authentication-automatically). It's a good idea to do a bit of research before posting questions - not only can you find an answer, but you may find alternatives as well.

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase Admin SDKs have the ability to disable user accounts. For example, on Node.js, you'd do this with:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
  disabled: true
})
```

For examples in the other supported languages, see the documentation on [updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).

Note that the Admin SDKs are designed to be used in trusted environments only, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. You cannot run this code in the client-side app, as that would allow any user to disable any other user's account.